What is a difference between an id set-up to use sesu vs. being added to sudoers file?
We are upgrading Confluent version in production, where the id we have to use is set-up with sesu vs.  in lower environments, the id that was used to execute Confluent provided ansible playbooks was part of the sudoers file.
The upgrade worked without any issues in lower environment, but in production, it is running into issues in reading the override.conf file - which is created when running the playbook with owner as root and permissions of 640.
Since the same playbooks worked in the lower environments and the only difference is the way the id is set-up in the two environments, I was trying to find the difference in the two.  Hopefully, this will help with being able to run the playbook successfully in production as well.
Is it possible to use the above mentioned set-up and still successfully run the playbooks with that id?
Thanks
UPDATE
@StephenKitt  Some more details that I could infer - looking at the ansible playbooks from Confluent and its relationship to my question.
In the provided playbook, in one of the tasks, the override.conf file is created at /etc/systemd/system/confluent-server.service.d/override.conf as root with 640 permissions
- name: Update system overrides with masterkey
  template:
    src: override.conf.j2
    dest: "{{ kafka_broker.systemd_override }}"
    mode: 0640
    owner: root
    group: root
  diff: "{{ not mask_sensitive_diff|bool }}"
  tags:
    - systemd
    - privileged

And the next task is to start the brokers.  When secrets_protection_enabled is true, the playbook tries to read the above file. And the broker fails to restart, if secrets_protection_enabled is set to false`, it doesn't need to read the above file and succeeds.
This worked in the lower environment where the id running the ansible playbook was in sudoers file, whereas in the DR environment, the id running the playbook is set-up with sesu access.
That is the only difference with respect to the environment when running the upgrade playbooks.
So, I thought the permissions to read a file created as root / root with 640 permissions has something to do with the issue.  In the sense that id with sudoers set-up can read it but id with sesu set-up doesn't have read permissions or belongs to 'other' in the permission hierarchy.
Hence, I am trying to find out if that is correct?  If it is how can it be fixed, if it is not, I have to do some more research to find the cause of the issue.
Thanks

sesu, is that the Symantec (Broadcom) tool? Have you set up the appropriate Ansible module?

Yes it is and we have this included in the hosts file ansible_become_method: sesu        ansible_become_exe: /opt/CA/AccessControl/bin/sesu .   Also, we were able to install the brokers when we set secrets_protection_enabled: false.  Only when that is enabled, it errors out.  Thanks

@StephenKitt - I have updated the question with some more information
